# AJAX Post request via API - error occurred while parsing request parameters

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, api

I'm trying to use AJAX to do a POST request via API. For some reason I run into this error:  **"error occurred while parsing request parameters".**

From my understanding, this error occured because of the json parsing when I pass the url attribute into the POST request.

I've read various stackoverflow post around the internet, and seems like using the following should work:

```
data: { todo: { user_id: userId, body: todoBody } },
datatype : 'json',
```

I've also tried using this as well and it doesn't work

```
data: { "todo": { "user_id": userId, "body": todoBody } },
datatype : 'json',
```

I hope someone can help guide me to the right direction :)

The following is the full code:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class='new-todo'>
    <%= form_for todo, remote: true do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body, 'Todo Item' %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 4, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter todo item" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-success', data: { user_id: current_user.id, user_token: current_user.auth_token} %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Api.js**

```
 var superlist = {};

superlist.setupDeleteHandlers = function() {

  $(document).ready(function(){


    $('.new-todo').submit(function(event) {
      var userId = $('.btn-success').attr("data-user-id");
      var userToken = $('.btn-success').attr("data-user-token");
      var todoBody = $('#todo_body').val();
      var data = {"todo": {"user_id": userId, "body":todoBody}};
      console.log("test", userId, userToken, todoBody, data);
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/api/users/"+userId+"/todos",
        data: { "todo": { "user_id": userId, "body": todoBody } },
        datatype : 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", userToken);
        },
        success : function() {
          alert('Item successfully created!'); 
        },
        error : function(error) {
        }
      });
    });

  });

};
```

Comment: instead of `{ "todo": { "user_id": userId, "body": todoBody } }` in ajax request data just use `data` variable.

Comment: Tried that (data: data) and it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/api/users/"+userId+"/todos",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", userToken);
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! I read in other stackoverflow post, using data: data, datatype : 'json' would work. Thank you so much for guiding me in the right direction! :)